# Treeview copy to RichtextBox or print

Tags: c#, treeview, richtextbox, rtf

I've a TreeView (directory tree) and like to 'copy' the checked (checkboxes) nodes to a RichTextBox or other control (In the end it needs to be printed). 
So the result is a custom tree (text and icons) which can be printed.
Is this possible?
 I couldn't find any usefull information with Google!
( Language: C# )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's a problem? Create new TreeView and copy resursively checked nodes from source TreeView to created one. Then use Control.DrawToBitmap() and print obtained bitmap.
For example:

```
void PrintNewTreeView()
{
    var pd = new PrintDocument();
    pd.PrintPage += OnPrintPage;
    pd.Print(); 
}

void OnPrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    var bitmap = new Bitmap(newTreeView.Bounds.Size);
    newTreeView.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.Size);
    var pt = Point.Empty; // drawing origin
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, pt);
}
```

Comment: And how to print the new one ?

Comment: This isnt an answer, its a comment really. It offers no actual solution or code, just what you have as an idea.

Comment: OnPrintPage returns error. So changed the original:         void OnPrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            Rectangle sourceRect = treeView2.ClientRectangle;

            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(sourceRect.Width, sourceRect.Height);
            treeView2.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, sourceRect);
            var pt = Point.Empty; // drawing origin
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, pt);
        }